# casting id on sequelize for association to other column

Tags: sequelize.js

https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/
any solution/ tips and trick about these association ?

i looking for custom propertis or casting in sequelize like in laravel that can override id relation use other column as relation instead . can i do the same thing ?

```
'use strict'
const { Model } = require('sequelize')
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class vw_monitor_jetty extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      models.vw_monitor_jetty.hasMany(models.file_storage_bunker, {
        // instead id , can i use detail_id as relation to model_id ? 
        foreignKey: 'model_id',
        constraint: false
      })
    }
  }
  vw_monitor_jetty.init(
    {
      user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      show_in: DataTypes.STRING,
      detail_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
)
  return vw_monitor_jetty
}
```

because its refer to a `views` from mysql . so i dont have id ,
i want to make its relation by `detail_id` to `model_id`

**vw_monitor_jetty** have `detail_id` thats refers to **file_storage_bunker** column `model_id`.

in my **file_storage_bunker** i have column

column `model` : 'form_chain_a' with column `detail_id`  : '1'

column `model` : 'form_chain_b' with column `detail_id`  : '1' // same 1 , but different model name.

could i use too include like these one

```
.findAndCountAll({
          include: [
{
              model: file_storage_bunker,
              separate: true,
              required: false,
//               where: {
//                model: 'form_tug_boat' // i could i can define by result of data but of course if i cant do like these, my point question just for manipulation or casting `id` to `detail_id` as key to relation on file_storage_bunker.
//               }
            }
]
```

Comment: Did you try `sourceKey` option next to `foreignKey` option to indicate `detail_id`?

Comment: as default `[sequelize]` is depend on `id` that can be auto relation to `model_id` in my code above . but my relation is between `detail_id` to `model_id` . the table is not a table, its a view from sql language and the id is `UUID()` from sql language. need to override or casting or use `detail_id` for relation .

Comment: I meant `hasMany(models.file_storage_bunker, {
        sourceKey: 'detail_id', 
        foreignKey: 'model_id',
        constraint: false
      })`

Comment: tomorrow i will check and try it .